# Cacti Thold: Enter my own baseline reference in the past

Tags: cacti

In my cacti 088a and Thold plugin (version 0.5) when using **Baseline Deviation** I can choose only

> 6 minutes average
>
> 24 minutes average
>
> 4.8 hours average

for `Time reference in the past`.

**Is there a way to specify my own reference in the past?**

I need to detect gradual but persistent decline in certain readings, say steady signal degradation within a whole month rather than just detecting rapid changes with those default time windows I listed above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to add my own by editing the database entry for the threshold template, in the following order but checked only for 48 hours will need some time to see what I actually need, like a month or more. 
Did it the following way but if anyone has suggestions this question remains open,

Created the template with the web gui,

changed the `thold_template` table's `bl_ref_time_range` to what I need, it's in seconds.

only then applied the template en masse to graphs. (The graphs can have only 1 threshold per data source... apparently.)